# Storing json objects in sql server using facebook api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am fetching friends of the logged in users on my website from facebook in the JsonObject in [name,uid] pair .

I have attached the debug image of the object.

[image]

I am referring to this [code](http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/) for reference

JSONObject me = api.Get("/me");
JSONObject meFriends = api.Get("/me/friends");

**How do i store extract and store the id and name of meFriends?**

I want to store this name value pair in sql database?

**Please help how could i achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `JSONObject meFriends = api.Get("/me/friends");` to `JSONObject meFriends = api.Get("/me/friends?fields=id,name");`
2. `foreach` thru the resulting data in `meFriends` and inside of it you will do steps 3-5
3. create a parameters array
4. assign the id and name from data
5. call insert sproc passing it the parameters array

Of course, I'd recommend you look into batch operations relating to your particular data adapter rather than killing your data store with umpteem-zillion calls, but I wanted the pseudo-code to be clear.

Depending upon the data store and the data adapter you use, they may already have ways to store arrays of objects without having to do what I showed above.